# Is supply reduction consider as a hard or soft fork?

Tags: development, currencies, blockchain-fork

I'm writing an article about current Minergate Dashcoin hard fork. From all the bitcoin hard fork talks I get the impression only when block size increases will result in a hard fork. How about coin reduction(for example, 10000 to 1) Is it considered as a hard fork? or not a fork at all? Assume the chain didn't split.

Comment: What do you mean with "coin deduction"? Are you talking about a reduction of the block reward? Alternatively, your title makes me think you meant a blocksize reduction?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Coin Reduction, I've changed the title. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So, each coin value will simply be divided by 10k and rounded down?

Comment: Yes, and all pools need to be upgraded.[thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1020627.0) community update #3.